# Subsetting a string based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, string

I have a vector where each element is a string.  I only want to keep the part of the string right before the '==' regardless of whether it is at the beginning of the string, after the & symbol, or after the | symbol.  Here is my data:

```
data <- c("name=='John'", "name=='David'&age=='50'|job=='Doctor'&city=='Liverpool'", 
"job=='engineer'&name=='Andrew'", 
"city=='Manchester'", "age=='40'&city=='London'"
)
```

My ideal format would be something like this:

```
[1] "name"
[2] "name" "age" "job" "city"
[3] "job" "name"
[4] "city" 
[5] "age" "city"
```

The closest I have got is using genXtract from the qdap library, which puts the data in the format above, but I only know how to use it with one condition, i.e.

```
qdap::genXtract(data, "&", "==")
```

But I don't just want the part of the string between & and == but also between | and == or the beginning of the string and ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this regex does, is capture all a-zA-Z0-9 (=letters and numbers) before an occurence of `==`.

```
stringr::str_extract_all( data, "[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=(==))")

[[1]]
[1] "name"
[[2]]
[1] "name" "age"  "job"  "city"
[[3]]
[1] "job"  "name"
[[4]]
[1] "city"
[[5]]
[1] "age"  "city"
```

if you want the output as a vector, use

```
L <- stringr::str_extract_all( data, "[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=(==))" )
unlist( lapply( L, paste, collapse = " " ) )
```

results in

```
[1] "name"             
[2] "name age job city"
[3] "job name"         
[4] "city"             
[5] "age city"
```

Comment: Is there anyway that this could also work if there are numbers because sometimes I have job1=="artist"&job2=="actor"

Comment: just a `0-9` between the square brackets..., see updated answer above

Comment: Also, on the other side, is there any way of saying before '==' or before '>=' ?

Comment: sure.. I suggest you do some reading about regexes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, this can be done with `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
lst1 <- regmatches(data, gregexpr("\\w+(?=\\={2})", data, perl = TRUE))
sapply(lst1, paste, collapse = " ")
#[1] "name"     
#[2] "name age job city" 
#[3] "job name"       
#[4]  "city"      
#[5]  "age city"
```